# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, lamp

I am trying to create a simple mailing list webpage. Using LAMP. Here is the code I have for connecting to my database:

```
<?php
    function insert()
    {
        $servername = "127.0.0.1";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "(my password here)";
        $dbname = "(my db name here)";

        try
        {
                // preparing database handle $dbh
                $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

            // set the PDO error mode to exception
                $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo ("Could not connect to server.\n");
                echo ("getMessage(): " . $e->getMessage () . "\n");
            }
      }

?>
```

The function continues after that but this connection attempt gets cung up on the catch, and throws the "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" error. I have tried:
-Changing the $servername to localhost, but this gives me a different error: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory"
-trying to specify all different ports
-checked all my info, database name and password.
-I can log into phpmyadmin and see that my database is fine
-looked at all other questions on this topic, with no help found.

Comment: use this and let me know `$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;port=8889;dbname=AppDatabase", $username, $password);`

Comment: nope, no success with this suggestion